# Slide-swipe menu in front of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu

I am looking or an library that can help me with an slide-swipe menu that loads in front of the current view; that doesn't push the current view to the side.

I have tried a bunch of different libraries, and can't find one that works for me. Also, I am not using Storyboard and most of those I find use Storyboard.

Among those I tried: `SWRevealViewController`, `ecslidingviewcontroller` (Storyboard, but tried to reuse code).

How can I either change `SWRevealViewController` to load on top of the current view, or is that another library which I must have missed which solved my problem?

Example:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide or show the view using UIViewAnimmation.
   Add new file like subviewcontroller and do the add subview for mainviewcontroller. 
   Try like this..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  subview =[[subviewcontroller alloc]init];
  [self.view addSubview:subview.view];
  viewVisible=YES;
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)showHideView {  
if (viewVisible) { 
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateImageOff" context:NULL]; 
    [subview.view setFrame:CGRectOffset(subview.view.frame, 150, 0)]; //-view1.frame.size.width
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
    viewVisible = NO;

} else { 
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateImageOn" context:NULL]; 
    [subview.view setFrame:CGRectOffset(subview.view.frame,-150, 0)]; //view1.frame.size.width
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
    viewVisible = YES;
}
}
```

Comment: You are right, I might just be overdoing it by adding a lib. I'll give it some thought

Answer (score 1):

i found the [JTRevealSlideBar](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo) to be very nice. you will just need to change how it does its animation so that it doesnt push the viewcontroller out the way

Comment: thnx. Good idea, but I am really looking for something straight out-of-the box, prefferably using cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

writing your simple custom animation and plug it to ECSlidingViewController should work